# swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types

Tags: python, smartcontracts, web3py

i've got error when passing parameters to contract function using web3.py. I think I pass readable data. Error:

```
Could not identify the intended function with name `swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'int'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`: ['swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint256,address[],address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

function call:

```
tx_info = pancake.functions.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    int(how_many_tokens_can_buy()*(10**getinfo()[-1])*(1-slippages)), 
    [checksum(wbnb), checksum(tokencontract)], 
    walletadr, 
    int(time.time()) + 10 * 60).buildTransaction(
    {
        'from': walletadr,
        'value': web3.toWei(howmuchbnb, 'ether'),
        'gas': gaslimit,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei(gasprice, 'Gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletadr),
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Parenthesis like:

```
...,(int(time.time()) + 10 * 60)).buildTransaction(...
```

that's all I can show you because this is (maybe) just a casting problem